# Remove old emails from a Lotus Notes database

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there a utility, plugin, application that can help an admin of a Lotus Notes(v6.5 Client)/Domino (v5) server to trim the fat from the database? But it needs to skip certain Users. I found the following tool: http://www.virtualobjectives.com.au/notesdomino/mailboxcleaner6.htm

I really do not know anything about administrating the backend of lotus notes. And I am not sure if the above utility will allow me filter the users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would've been better served in ServerFault.

You don't need a 3rd party tool, Notes already comes with archiving.

You can enable scheduled archiving. Bring up the Archive Settings in database properties. Enable and customise an archive profile i.e. archive messages old than N days. And finally  make sure you select "Just clean up this database without archiving".

For more details check out Lotus Notes help pages.